# How must HQL Date strings be formatted for query without using binding?

Tags: hibernate, hql

I am in a position where I need to be able to query our database for records between two dates (java.util.Date), but I cannot use the standard method of binding dates to parameters in a query.

I am generating a filter dynamically in client code (using GWT) to be attached to the query created by our "get" method used for all of our data requests. I am trying to create a simple "where" clause as such:

```
where groupCheckInDate >= 2014-10-01 00:00:00 AND groupCheckInDate <= 2014-10-31 00:00:00
```

I've searched everywhere I could think of and have only been able to find clues that my date string format is wrong. I tried using **yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss** as my format string, but this is not working. I'm getting the following error:

```
org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: 00 
near line 1, column 84 [from Receipts where date >= 
2014-10-01 00:00:00 AND date <= 2014-10-31 00:00:00 order by id]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really have to use in-lined strings, you should escape them. This for example should work for SQL Server:

```
where groupCheckInDate >= '2014-10-01 00:00:00' 
  AND groupCheckInDate <= '2014-10-31 00:00:00'
```

The point is that the hql parser will treat the content between `''` as a single statement. Without it, each number is evaluated... causing exception

Comment: We're using SQL Server for development, but the final product will likely use PostgresQL, or possibly any other flavor. We want to make this as platform independent as possible.

Comment: This will work, I'd say. But you should use **parameters** to be sure, that the proper `dialect` will resolve any DB engine specific requirements... good luck with Hibernate